# Simple way of getting the date

Tags: php, date

I have date in this format: 2010-01-11.  I want to display JAN-11.  How can i do this using php?

Comment: I'm not sure php can get you a date. You might have better luck visiting a bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudu's answer is correct, +1.

"M-y" would result to "Jan-11"
so if you need the output to be UPPERCASE,  dont forget to use strtoupper().

```
<?php echo strtoupper(date("M-y",strtotime("2010-01-11")));?>
```

also bookmark this for later reference.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Cheers

Comment: Fair point, although you could CSS style the text to uppercase too ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php echo date("M-y",strtotime("2010-01-11"));?>
```